# Hashmap,wicket and timer?

Tags: java, timer, wicket

At the moment I have a hashamp stores new user registrations that registered on the webpage, however I want to clear the hashmap at 8.00 am in the morning. I can not use java timer as it gives me an error, due to the use of wicket. Can anyone point me in the right direction ? I get the time in millies and compare the dates, however the way my webpage app is set up it would require the user the click refresh at exatcly 8.00 am.

Tnx

```
                        Timer timer = new Timer ();

            TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
                @Override
                public void run () {
                  sCached=false;

                }
            };
            timer.schedule (hourlyTask, 01, 60);
```

Comment: Create a new Thread and check the time. See

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403755/how-to-create-a-thread-that-runs-all-the-time-my-application-is-running

Comment: Thread could be a bad idea..

Comment: How about using a dedicated framework for scheduling? This might be an overkill for just one usecase but there might be others waiting... [Quartz](http://terracotta.org/products/quartz-scheduler) by Terracotta has been used successfully with wicket applications

Comment: Is there anything simpler this seems like an overkill..

Comment: Please, provide your code snippet relevant to the HashMap and timer and the exception. Where is your HashMap referenced? In the WebApplication singelton instance? I use Quartz together with Wicket without any problem, so probably we can think about a solution. However, it would be possible to use your solution as well.

Comment: Why is using a thread a bad idea? Java timer uses a thread. I'm using ScheduledExecutorService in a ServletContextListener to preform daily tasks in a Wicket application.

Comment: I updated my post have a look at the code, the problem now I am having  everytime the page is refreshed there is a new timer.If I have 5 people on the website 5 timers will be created @pikand

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to store somewhere the date-time of the last time the new user registrations hashmap was cleared.

On every read from or write to this hashmap, determine whether this hashmap should have been cleared since this last clearance date-time. If no then do nothing, otherwise clear the hashmap and update the clearance date-time before doing the read or write.

This way, you change how you update the hashmap from a timed basis to an eventing basis.